# Injecting a spinner inside a fullcalendar table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar in my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rbynbu4z/4/) that displays events as a number inside each days cell. Is it possible, when triggering the day click or the event item click, to replace the number with a spinner. Then when I finish pulling the event data and displaying, etc, etc I put the number back and hide the spinner?

Update! - I can change the value of the cell event item to a spinner when I click on the item inside the cell like this

```
eventLimitClick: function (cellInfo, jsEvent) {
                var eventValue = $(cellInfo.moreEl).html();
                $(cellInfo.moreEl).html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i>');
            },
```

Update! - I got the day click to show a spinner

```
dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            var elementValue = $(jsEvent.target).text();
            $(jsEvent.target).html('<div><a class="fc-more"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i></a></div>');
```

but I'm having a harder time changing it when I trigger a day click. 'this' in the callback, which is a 'td' element, is for a different table then the one used for the event item value. If I can just figure out how to change the element holding the value from a dayclick I'll be good to go! Or if I can trigger a eventLimitClick from a day click I'll accept that!! Is that possible?

Here is some code below

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: ''
},
//defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
defaultView: 'basicWeek',
editable: false,
height: 174,
eventLimit: 1,
eventLimitText: function(numEvents) {
  return numEvents;
},
eventLimitClick: function (cellInfo, jsEvent) {
},
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

},
events: [{
    title: 'Event',
    start: '2017-09-28'
  },
  {
    title: 'Event',
    start: '2017-09-28'
  }
]
});

});
```

```css
td.fc-more-cell {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.3em;
}

.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton,
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td,
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton table,
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton tr {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td div {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            var elementValue = $(jsEvent.target).text();
            $(jsEvent.target).html('<div><a class="fc-more"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i></a></div>');
```